# Adding a TabView to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I have my MainActivity with a ViewPager, if you swipe from left to right you change the fragment! I need a View with Tabs in the third fragment, so I started trying to implement a TabHost. But I don't really know how to to this. I wan't the TabHost to contain 5tabs, for evry tab there is also an TabActivity.
But how can I implement a TabView?

**The solution**

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.third_frag);

Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Satz 1"),
    Tab1Activity.class, arg1);

Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Satz 2"),
    Tab2Activity.class, arg2);

Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Satz 3"),
    Tab3Activity.class, arg3);

Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag4", 4);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Satz 4"),
    Tab4Activity.class, arg4);

Bundle arg5 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag5", 5);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator("Satz 5"),
    Tab5Activity.class, arg5);

return mTabHost;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
super.onDestroyView();
mTabHost = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use to follow this [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging) swipe views with Tabhost is bit complicated.

Comment: hmm ok but there isn't the solution, I don't want the tabs to switch between the fragments, I want the 5 tabs in the third fragment, so I can switch in the third fragment between the tabs!

Comment: @gewhjhfkgad in the xml file of the third fragments just add the <ViewPager> in thirdfragment.xml and attach the PagerAdapter read it carefully

Comment: @gewhjhfkgad Check out this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ .

Comment: So I have to make a second ViewPager, because one is for swipping between fragments and the other should be for swipping between the tabs

Comment: yeah^^ thanks for the help, I will write later again:)

Comment: I made it the easy way, I didn't set a tabhost in the layout. I made Tabs and and a TabHost promatically, and that works fine..

Comment: @gewhjhfkgad can u just upload the snippet